# How can i store execution plans for certain stored procs

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2014, execution-plan

Unfortunately we cannot use query store as we are on SQL 2014 and need to find a way to store execution plans of certain stored procedures.

I saw XE like sp statement completed but unfortunately it seems it does not see
to store query plans.

Is there a way i can store execution plan of stored procs which executes not more than 5 times a day and can compare the plans , lets say for couple of weeks.

Comment: do you control the application that runs the sproc or are able to modify the sproc itself? do you care about differences between actual / estimated plans? what's the lifetime like of your plan cache (does a plan live there for a few minutes / hours / days)?

Comment: Use at your own risk, I have no knowledge of this project, but it purports ot add QueryStore like functionality to earlier versions of SQL Server. 
 https://dbafromthecold.com/2017/08/19/query-store-functionality-in-earlier-versions-of-sql-server/

Comment: @TZHX- No i am not, but i do have approval to do so. Plan age is about 6 hours. This database is LS secondary which gets log restored via LS every 6 hours so plan will be remove from cache

Comment: @JonathanFite- but that does not solve the problem of storing exec plan for couple of procs. I mean i cant filter as this seems to collect lot of data which i dont need to troubleshoot right now